# Am I doing something wrong with C++ std::semaphore or are they just not useful for signaling in this way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, semaphore, thread-synchronization

I am working on a multi threaded program where a looping streaming thread blocks/sleeps/waits for indication from a control thread to run in its loop, and can then be 'paused' when the user disables all streams.

Usually I would use condition variables for something like this, however due to the nature of the problem (any streams being requested should allow the loop to start, and it should only stop when the last stream is requested to be disabled) I think that solution would be more complicated than I would like (not very complicated, but would need more bookkeeping at least). I'm trying to see if semaphores are a good choice for this after [reading about them here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore):

> Semaphores are also often used for the semantics of signalling/notifying rather than mutual exclusion, by initializing the semaphore with ​0​ and thus blocking the receiver(s) that try to acquire(), until the notifier "signals" by invoking release(n). In this respect semaphores can be considered alternatives to std::condition_variables, often with better performance.

I mocked up a simple example since this is my first time using C++20 `std::semaphore`s, but this example does not work as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <semaphore>
#include <unistd.h>

std::counting_semaphore streams_sem{0};

void stream_thread(){
  while (1){
    streams_sem.acquire();
    std::cout << "Sending images!\n";
    usleep(500000);
    streams_sem.release();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]){
  std::thread t1(stream_thread);
  t1.detach();
  std::cout << "Main thread starting streams\n";
  streams_sem.release();
  usleep(3e6);
  std::cout << "Main thread stopping streams\n";
  streams_sem.acquire();

  return 0;
}
```

When run, this is the output I get:

```
Main thread starting streams
Sending images!
Sending images!
Sending images!
Sending images!
Sending images!
Sending images!
Main thread stopping streams
Sending images!
Sending images!
... and on
```

I can assume that the main thread is not ever getting scheduled in a time between the looping `release()` and `acquire()`, although I would have expected it catch it eventually (in a timely manner, a few sec tops) since the main thread is already blocked on `acquire()` and because of the above comparison to condition variables.

This leads me to my main (sub)questions:

1. What kind of pitfalls may I encounter if any (besides just wasting time) by having a short (10-100uS) sleep after the `release()` in the looping thread? IE Could that still have a likely chance to fail to stop it, making it a bad solution?
2. Is this an inappropriate or invalid use of semaphores? Or is there something else I could do so they would act more like a signal/condition variable with an inbuilt counter?

I would also be open to any other ways I could achieve this functionality. I am trying to avoid using condition variables for this since I believe the solution would be complicated, but if there is another synchronization method that seems like a better fit, I would love to hear about that as well.

**------Edit: Relevant information------**

In practice, these streams are essentially always available and protected on their own during access, so the only functionality I need here is to know if any are active (I could technically just make it a busy loop and check if each stream is active always, but want a lightweight way that would block when none are requested).

Comment: There's a separate issue that if your main thread does successfully acquire the semaphore, it will try to return without having joined the thread, which is bad and causes `std::terminate` to be called.  Except in cases of unrecoverable error, you have to have your threads return voluntarily and then join them.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is just with a `std::atomic<bool> quit;`.  The stream thread does `if (quit) return;` on each iteration, and the main thread does `quit = true; t1.join();`. You can weaken those to `std::memory_order_relaxed` for improved efficiency, if you like.

Comment: @NateEldredge valid point, I had fixed that while creating the MRE but not in the post. Edited to fix, thank you. I appreciate the suggestion as well, using a boolean in that way would be a bit of extra logic that a counting semaphore would have taken care of in my real use case, but that can definitely be done and is more in my comfort zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can assume that the main thread is not ever getting scheduled in a time between the looping release() and acquire(), although I would have expected it catch it eventually (in a timely manner, a few sec tops) since the main thread is already blocked on acquire() and because of the above comparison to condition variables

There's literally *one* instruction between the release and re-acquire, it's an unconditional jump. You're being extremely optimistic about the likelihood of the main thread getting in there.

As I understand it, your logic is supposed to be something like:

1. The semaphore counter represents the number of active streams
2. The thread should keep processing streams while that number is non-zero
3. Another thread is responsible for starting/stopping streams (incrementing/decrementing the counter)

Nothing there suggests the worker thread should *ever* modify the number of streams. So semaphores are at least not a perfect fit.

If we accept the thread is using semaphores to check for a non-zero counter, it should just acquire and immediately release, before doing the work.

This leaves out all discussion of what these streams are and how it coordinates access to them with the main thread. This is the stuff that would normally be protected by the mutex associated with a condition variable.

That is to say, I'm not convinced that this example shows all the shared state that needs to be synchronized, and if you have to add a mutex anyway, the semaphore doesn't end up being simpler than a regular condition variable.

Comment: In fact, I think the compiler would even be justified in optimizing out the release/acquire pair and just letting the thread hold the semaphore permanently, since there is no guarantee that another thread would be able to take it.

Comment: I completely overlooked that I could acquire and immediately release in the stream thread. The processing and transmission that would occur when any stream is active would likely be on the order of 500mS. That being said, and with my edit at the bottom of the question: Would you still say that a semaphore is not the right choice here? I could definitely solve this with a condition variable, but doing so would mean the main thread needs to check all streams, which means locking a mutex ~20x and a lot of extra logic so that I could set a predicate when none are active, which I hoped to avoid

Comment: Adding another comment for anyone that may come across this; There is an easier way. The semaphore functionality could be replaced in my case by a simple static integer and proper condition variable with predicate, I was hyper focused on the shiny new c++20 feature and overlooked the simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

C++ threading primitives do not provide fairness.

If you are waiting on a condition variable or a semaphore and it is opened, you don't get "the next chance at it".  Anyone could get it, including someone who isn't waiting yet.

```
void stream_thread(){
  while (1){
    // XXXXX
    streams_sem.acquire();
    // YYYYY
    std::cout << "Sending images!\n";
    usleep(500000);
    // YYYYY
    streams_sem.release();
    // XXXXX
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]){
  std::thread t1(stream_thread);
  t1.detach();
  std::cout << "Main thread starting streams\n";
  // BBBBB
  streams_sem.release();
  // AAAAA
  usleep(3e6);
  std::cout << "Main thread stopping streams\n";
  // AAAAA
  streams_sem.acquire(); // 11111
  // BBBBB

  return 0;
}
```

the only thing you can really say about your code is that you won't be in both `BBBBB` and `XXXXX` regions of the code at the same time.

What you appear to want is instead, when main reaches `11111`, the `stream_thread` loop won't be allowed to progress.

This can be done in a few ways.  You could add a `std::atomic<bool>`.  In `stream_thread` you can refuse to attempt to `acquire` when it is `true` -- just spin on it.

In `main`, you set it to true before the line `11111`.  Then you acquire.

This asymmetry means that your `acquire` gets to evaluate, and you get the behavior you are asking for.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/ahqoMGWaa):

```
std::counting_semaphore streams_sem{0};
std::atomic<bool> guard = false;

void stream_thread(){
  while (1){
    while (guard) {}
    streams_sem.acquire();
    std::cout << "Sending images!\n";
    usleep(50);
    streams_sem.release();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]){
  std::thread t1(stream_thread);
  t1.detach();
  std::cout << "Main thread starting streams\n";
  streams_sem.release();
  usleep(3e2);
  std::cout << "Main thread stopping streams\n";
  guard = true;
  streams_sem.acquire();
  std::cout << "Shutdown\n";

  return 0;
}
```

the trick here is I broke the symmetry.  The main thread can raise the guard, and the stream thread cannot lower it or prevent the main thread from doing so.

Without that symmetry breaking, the stream thread never giving up its right to run is a valid program result.  And as semaphore interaction doesn't suspend the active thread, "never giving it up" is a high likelihood result.